# How to pass {{value}} in HTML to component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I Used REACTIVE FORM.
My Code HTML:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="directionId" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

How to receive value **{{item.name}}** in Component.ts ?

Comment: Can you please share details about the component and the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6a2yyt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of list" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} </option>
</select>
```

.ts

```
onChange(value: any){
    console.log(value) // this is id;
    let name = this.list.find(x => x.id == value).name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Template file  - bind on change event on `select element` `(change)`
>   and assign a function `onChange`

```
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of list" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.value}}</option>
    </select>
```

> ts class file - define a function `onChange` which invoke when
>   `change event` fire

```
 onChange(value: any){
        console.log(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to loop the select? If that is not cause and you want to loop `<option>` then this will help you for sure.

**component.html**

```
 <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"  >
     <option  *ngFor="let item of list" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  list=[{
    'id':"1",
    'name':'ABC'
  },{
    'id':"2",
    'name':'ZXZ'}
  ];
  onChange(value: any){
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

> Stackbliz is here
>   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8gau2

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="directionId" *ngFor="let item of list" (change)="getSelectedOptionText($event)">
                       <option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>

      </select>
```

```
getSelectedOptionText(event: Event) {
   let selectedOptions = event.target['options'];
   let selectedIndex = selectedOptions.selectedIndex;
   let selectElementText = selectedOptions[selectedIndex].text;
   console.log(selectElementText)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ***ngFor** from **select tag** because we have to display only one drop down with multiple options. So move your *ngFor in **option** tag

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="directionId" >
        <option value="{{item.id}}" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your code as follows:

```
{{item.id}} to {{item.Name}}
```